# Search for a keyword in a text file

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have to write a program that asks the user to enter a keyword,after that it should open a text file and write to the console each line that contains the keyword.

I will need to use the `.Contains()` method to search a for text in a particular string. The text being searched should be passed as a parameter."

What i have so far is:

```
    Sub Main()
       Console.Write("Please enter a keyword: ")
       Dim keyword As String = Console.ReadLine()

       Dim filePath As String = "C:\...\Projects\testing.txt"
       Dim fileHolder As System.IO.StreamReader
       Dim sentence As String
       fileHolder = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileReader(filePath)
       sentence = fileHolder.ReadLine()
```

Any hints or tips will help. Thanks!

Comment: Looks like homework for me ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
Console.Write("Please enter a keyword: ")
Dim keyword As String = Console.ReadLine()

Dim filePath As String = "C:\a.txt"
Dim lines() As String = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(filePath)
For i = 0 To lines.Length - 1
    If lines(i).Contains(keyword) Then Console.WriteLine(lines(i))
Next
Console.ReadKey()
```

You can also do it without looping like this:

```
Console.Write("Please enter a keyword: ")
Dim keyword As String = Console.ReadLine()

Dim filePath As String = "C:\a.txt"
Dim lines() As String = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(filePath)
Dim filteredLines As String = String.Join(vbNewLine, lines.Where(Function(line As String) line.Contains(keyword)).ToArray())
Console.WriteLine(filteredLines)
Console.ReadKey()
```

This code also can be shortened to:

```
Console.Write("Please enter a keyword: ")
Dim keyword As String = Console.ReadLine()
Dim filteredLines As String = String.Join(vbNewLine, System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\a.txt").Where(Function(line As String) line.Contains(keyword)).ToArray())
Console.WriteLine(filteredLines)
Console.ReadKey()
```

Comment: In the first snippet, you are bringing all lines to memory. But what if it is a huge file (with many lines if we are lucky, instead of everything in one line), and won't bringing all lines to memory be... too much?
I feel it might be better if you'd use ReadLine() every time instead of reading it at once.